# How to add request attribute through spring webflux integration for outbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Below is outbound gateway configuration

```
<outbound-gateway id="reactiveFullConfig"
              url="http://localhost:8080/hello"
              http-method="GET"
              request-channel="requests"
              reply-timeout="1234"
              extract-request-payload="false"
              expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
              mapped-request-headers="requestHeader1, requestHeader2"
              mapped-response-headers="responseHeader"
              reply-channel="replies"
              charset="UTF-8"
              order="77"
              auto-startup="false"
              transfer-cookies="true"
              reply-payload-to-flux="true"
              body-extractor="bodyExtractor"
              publisher-element-type-expression="headers.elementType"
              extract-response-body="false">
<uri-variable name="foo" expression="headers.bar"/>
```

I have a requirement to set request attribute before sending request to request channel.Also the value of attribute can be different for each request.

Something similar to below if i have webclient object where the value for attribute MYCUSTOMATTRIBUTE_1(which is "customvalue" in below example) can be updated before each request.

```
webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/hello")
                .attribute("MYCUSTOMATTRIBUTE_1", "customvalue")
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(String.class)
                .block()        
                .getBody();
```

Using spring gateway xml, i am sending request on request channel using below code:

```
DirectChannel requestChannel = context.getBean("requestChannel", DirectChannel.class);
requestChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test message")).build());
```

**Does spring webflux integration provide a way to do the same?**

I also tried to pass value through Message object header using below code but i am not getting my custom header which is requestHeader1 in clientrequest. Note that requestheader1 is added in mapped-request-headers attribute.

```
requestChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test message")).setHeader(requestHeader1,"customvalue").build());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `attributes` support in the `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler` at the moment. And there is no an easy workaround : you must use that your custom `WebClient` instead.

I would like to understand the reason behind those attributes for you since I don't see how thy effect the target HTTP request. From the code I have so far it only leads into a deprecated method:

```
/**
 * Variant of {@link #basicAuthentication(String, String)} that looks up
 * the {@link Credentials Credentials} in a
 * {@link #BASIC_AUTHENTICATION_CREDENTIALS_ATTRIBUTE request attribute}.
 * @return the filter to use
 * @see Credentials
 * @deprecated as of Spring 5.1 in favor of using
 * {@link HttpHeaders#setBasicAuth(String, String)} while building the request.
 */
@Deprecated
public static ExchangeFilterFunction basicAuthentication() {
```

So, sounds like Spring Framework is discontinuing `atrributes` the redundant feature.

Comment: Currently I need to pass value in custom attributes and checking those attributes in exchangefilter to do some extra processing according to business logic. These attributes are dynamic in nature and user can add values to these attributes before sending request on request channel. Is there any other way i can pass the information which will gets added to ClientRequest object.I have access to ClientRequest Object in exchange filter from where i can fetch the values.

Comment: Even if i pass attributes in my custom webclient, i didnt see those getting copied in WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java. Only the headers are getting copied. 
                                                                                                     
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/webflux/outbound/WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java#L233

Comment: Right. My point was to have a POJO service activator with your logic around `WebClient`

Comment: Why cannot you pass that info via message headers and then consult request headers in in your filter instead of attributes? You then can remove that header from request?

Comment: i tried the same but we need to pass an object in header value which doesnt seems to be working. Currently i am setting header key and value object in Message Object before sending request to request channel.Is there a workaround to fetch header key and value object from Message Object and set it in ClientRequest object which can be used in filters.

Comment: Well, that is what your `mapped-request-headers="requestHeader1, requestHeader2"` supposed to do. It does remap headers from message to request. I assume that filter is called later on when request is prepared already.

Comment: Thanks Artem. It would be great if i get an example of mapped-request-headers implementation.